# ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/

Tags: android

I'm getting this error. It's saying `ClassLoader referenced unknown path`
And I don't know what to do? Can anyone solve my problem?

```
03-11 01:35:46.231 3040-3040/com.pptsindia.feedapp I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-11 01:35:46.418 3040-3040/com.pptsindia.feedapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.pptsindia.feedapp-1/lib/x86
03-11 01:35:46.884 3040-3040/com.pptsindia.feedapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-11 01:35:46.886 3040-3040/com.pptsindia.feedapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.pptsindia.feedapp, PID: 3040
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pptsindia.feedapp/com.pptsindia.feedapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
           at com.pptsindia.feedapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:33)
           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:602)
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
           at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
           at com.pptsindia.feedapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:33) 
           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339) 
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:602) 
           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237) 
           at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "at.markushi.ui.CircleButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pptsindia.feedapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.pptsindia.feedapp-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:583)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
            at com.pptsindia.feedapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:33) 
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339) 
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:602) 
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237) 
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 30 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
03-11 01:35:51.964 3040-3040/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3040 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 18):

For those who will find this thread in the future still looking for answer (just as I did).

> W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/[...]/lib/x86

was the only error/warning I had in LogCat. After trying almost anything, cleaning app data in Android OS (Settings -> Applications -> MyApp -> Memory -> Clear data) was the only solution that worked.

I hope that it helps someone.

Comment: Hi erwilka,You are right.But how can user recognize that has to clear data using(Settings -> Applications -> MyApp -> Memory -> Clear data).
Is it any alternate way to prevent this manually.

Comment: Vikas Gaurav, I experienced this problem only on development stage when compiling the app after minor changes in layout files. After successful installation the problem never appeared again.

Answer (score 13):

> W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.pptsindia.feedapp-1/lib/x86

Is not an error. It is a warning from the system.

Your error is actually a little bit below:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.pptsindia.feedapp, PID: 3040
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pptsindia.feedapp/com.pptsindia.feedapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class at.markushi.ui.CircleButton

Basically you have a problem on your XML file.

So you have to keep reading the stack to make sure you get to the root of your problem. As you can see logcat show a prefix on every line it logs

> - `V` — Verbose (lowest priority)
> - `D` — Debug
> - `I` — Info
> - `W` — Warning
> - `E` — Error
> - `F` — Fatal
> - `S` — Silent (highest priority, on which nothing is ever printed)

More information on [Android Developer - Debugging log](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html).

---

**EDIT**

Without further information it is impossible to know what the actual problem was. You would have to provide your XML file, but in that case I would suggest you open another question for that.

Comment: What do you mean by "Basically you have a problem on your XML file"? Why type? How to solve it? Doesnt make sense for him to keep reading the log when he doesnt know what he is looking for.

Comment: @ErnestoCejas He is asking about an error that has nothing to do with the message he provided. The message concerns a warning. His actual problem is related to the formation of his XML which is impossible to know without more information. If he wants to solve the XML problem I would suggest opening another question.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was **Instant Run** in Android Studio 3.0. I've disabled it and I finally could run app in debug mode!

Looks like Instant Run is still buggy...

To find it: **File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run**

Comment: Thanks - this appears to have worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was that MyActivity was missing in APK's dex.

It was not compiled and not included into build at all because it was a Kotlin class (MyActivity.kt) and Kotlin plugin was not enabled in "build.gradle" file of the app module (by mistake).