# Application close immediatly after start-up

Tags: java, android, code-injection, dagger-2, butterknife

- My application close just after it is build with success and loaded into my device

Actually it is the fullstack trace :

```
/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.akadream.musicplayer.MOCK-1/lib/arm64
I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30693 SIG: 9
```

### EDIT :

- The only thing configured for now in the project is the injection with Dagger and everything compile correctly

Comment: Clear your build and re-build again.

Comment: Already tried several times, also i tried invalidate cache and restart several times. I tried to debug with breakpoints but the application doesn't even start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926287/classloader-referenced-unknown-path-data-app)

Comment: @DavidRawson I posted the solution I found

Comment: It's not the full stack trace. You need to turn the filter off to see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !

In the Application class I had a cast that were throwing an exception.

`Cannot cast Application to CustomApplication`

I just forgot to add `android:name=".CustomApplication"` in the manifest