# When I launch android app I can see in logcat a warn and terminate app

Tags: android-studio

'''
Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
'''

Comment: Kindly add the logcat text or a screenshot so that the problem will be clear.

Comment: **first line** '10-15 19:53:45.463 8502-8502/com.example.beautifulsrilanka W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.beautifulsrilanka-1/lib/arm '

Comment: **second line** '10-15 19:53:45.593 8502-8502/com.example.beautifulsrilanka W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
' @AdnanTemur

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926287/classloader-referenced-unknown-path-data-app I think you are using some Github library

Comment: Yes,that was,I found my warn due to memory problem